# Betheme - On related posts, change read more button text for specific category

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I am using Betheme on WordPress.

Under the related posts section, is it possible to change the 'read more' button for a specific post category?

I've created a podcast page, so would prefer the text to read 'listen now' just for that category.

You can translate the text in the theme options, but this applies to the whole site, and I would like it just for the specific category - podcasts (id-1396).

Comment: The appropriate hook would be https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content_more_link/, but that doesn't get any information about the post passed in - so to determine the category for the post this is currently executing for, you will probably have to go via the global $post.